# Upgrading from 2.4.3 to 2.4.3-p3

Tags: upgrade, magento2.4.3

I am upgrading from 2.4.3 to 2.4.3-p3 and I have a few questions.

In composer.json should I only be chnaging these 3 lines?

"version": "2.4.3-p3",

"magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.4.3-p3",

"magento/data-migration-tool": "2.4.3", (This was 2.3.4 previously)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the complete commands you can run it is tested and working perfectly:**

bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

bin/magento maintenance:enable

cp composer.json composer.json.bak

cp composer.lock composer.lock.bak

composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin --no-update

composer update

composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p3 --no-update

composer update

bin/magento c:f

bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento s:d:c

bin/magento maintenance:disable

Answer (score 0):

No, when upgrading the magento to a newer version you **should not modify the composer files (composer.json and composer.lock)** , these files will be modified automatically when you run composer commands via command line, to upgrade to a newer version follow this official link - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html

**Or you can also try the below steps which I recommend:**

1. Switch the PHP CLI version by following this [link](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html) , for 2.4.3 it is 7.4
2. Switch to developer mode so that after upgrade static files will be generated automatically
3. First enable the maintenance mode with this command = bin/magento maintenance:enable (This is recommended if your server setup is in production and actual customers are engaged in your site or else if this is a local dev environment not needed)
4. Take a backup of the composer files so in the case when there is an issue you can easily revert it back =
5. cp composer.json composer.json.bak
6. cp composer.lock composer.lock.bak
7. composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin --no-update
8. composer update
9. composer require-commerce magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3-p3 --no-update
10. composer update
11. Clean the existing magento generated files such as cache , generated folders , static files etc by following the below commands
12. bin/magento cache:clean
13. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
14. bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento s:d:c
15. Disable the maintenance mode if enabled by this command = bin/magento maintenance:disable

**If any more help is needed when version upgrade , please do let me know in comments and if this worked please do give me like this motivates me and help answer more questions.Have a nice day.**

Comment: I have tried but not working with magento cloud project.